# Planning a party with peace

Tags: algorithm, permutation

There are n people some of them hate each other, some of them love each other and some of them don't know each other... If (A hates B and A sit next to B) or (A love B and A does not sit next to B) It will be a war. I am preparing my friend's birthday party so I don't want the party become a battlefield, I have a list like this:

a1 hates a2

a1 loves a3

a3 loves a2

...

Is there a efficient algorithm to arrange my friend's friends seat such that we will have no war ?

I am currently using nave brute force solution, generate all permutation to find a feasible arrangement.

Comment: this comes to mind http://blog.blprnt.com/blog/blprnt/all-the-names

Comment: Post it on http://math.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Tell us more about the seating arrangement, if it is indeed circular tables - check out Heuster's answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should approach this as a graph problem. I assumed that you want to seat the guests in a circle.

Let `V` be your set of guests. And let `E` be the set of all pairs of vertices `(A, B)` such that `A` and `B` do not hate each other. Finding a hamiltonian cycle in this graph already solves the problem that people who hate each other cannot sit next to each other, because those edges do not exist.

Now you need to enforce that people that love each other sit next to each other. For every pair of vertices `(A, B)` such that `A` and `B` love each other, add vertices `A'` and `B'` with edges `(A, A')`, `(B, B')`, and `(A', B')`. Both `A'` and `B'` have degree `2`, so your hamiltonian cycle has to contain `(A', B')`.

Now, simply find the hamiltonian cycle and you have your seat layout. Unfortunately this problem is NP complete, but at least it is well-studied.

Answer (score 1):

If you care about more than adjacent positioning (for instance if people cannot sit opposite to one another) then I would personally use a [genetic algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm).

You know what qualifies as a good match, but it's hard to get there.

**PSEUDO CODE ALERT**

Let's say you have a data model for a person

```
person
  +loves : person[]
  +hates : person[]
  +id : string //typically name, or a b c in your example
```

And you have a function to calculate the fit of two people

```
okToSitNextToEachOther(person1 : person, person2 : person) 
   return (person1.loves.contains(person1) ? 1 : 0) + 
          (person1.hates.contains(person2) ? -2 : 0); // hate more important than love
          //do the same for person2 if hate/love is directional
```

Create a data model of your table arrangement. Then make a function that evaluates the fit of the arrangement.

```
table
  -x : int //length of a table side, set in constructor
  +seatRow1 : person[x]
  +seatRow2 : person[x]
  +calculateMatch() : float //you could return int of error count or a percentage
  +mutate() : void // randomly swap people who violates your rule around
```

Create a manager that populates x tables randomly (enough tables for your population). 
Have the manager be able to mutate the data for the tables that matches least. (Mutate means to swap people around).

```
PartyManager
  -people : person[] //pass in constructor
  -tables : table[]
  +calculateMatch() : float //iterate over all tables and return sum of match
  +mutate() : void //iterate over all tables and mutate those who does not suit match requirement
  +clone() : PartyManager //clone this
```

Now create many managers and have them all in a list.
Loop until one of the managers has a 'good enough' arrangement. Until then. Call mutate on every manager. Delete the least successful ones, and create a new one for each you delete, and use the most successful as a seed, then run mutate on those.

```
PartyManager match = null
while (true) {
   PartyManager bestManager = managers.max( m => m.calculateMatch() ) //find the best match
   for each partyManager in managers
       if partyManager.calculateMatch() < TOO_BAD
           clone = bestManager.clone()
           clone.mutate()
           managers.add(clone)
           managers.remove(partyManager)
       else if partyManager.calculateMatch() < GOOD_ENOUGH
           partyManager.mutate()
       else
           match = partyManager // we fount a match
           break
```

I can fill inn more information if you need me to, but check out the wiki I linked to over.

Comment: Thank you, I think I will use this for my birthday :)

Comment: @make_lover Learning a constraint solver like [z3](http://z3.codeplex.com/) would be a better way to approach this mathematically clean problem.